# How to get request parameter in xml file

Tags: php, xml, twilio, twilio-api

I have one `callForward.xml` file which have some code like this, and I want to replace this {{PhoneNumber}} with the real number by calling the url like: 
https://example.com/callForward.xml?PhoneNumber=+911234567890,
Please suggest how to get it in the xml file?

Thank you in advance

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial>{{PhoneNumber}}</Dial>
    <Say>Hello, Have a good day!</Say>
</Response>
```

Use of this file is to dial the number dynamical I have tried with .php file like below

```html
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial>'.$_REQUEST['PhoneNumber'].'</Dial>
    <Say>Goodbye</Say>
</Response>';
```

but it gives an error  Error - 12100 Document parse failure

**NOTE** Can not edit the file after requesting the url. Twilio third part will read this file

Comment: Your web server is not going to process a URL ending in `.xml` with PHP. Set it up to do that, or make your URL `callForward.php` instead. Make sure you use `header()` function to send the data as XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the solution by Twimil Bin app

https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/230878368-How-to-use-templates-with-TwiML-Bins

Create Twimil bin app and copy URL and pass whatever you would like to add dynamically

like: `https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EHb1d23ebc567f87f6a211d48d7abe?PhoneNumber=+91123456789`

And it will replace the `{{PhoneNumber}}` value [image]

Answer (score 0):

XML is a static format; if you wish for the XML output to contain dynamic content, then you must write a server-side script that responds to query parameters and outputs XML text dynamically.  I assume you're using PHP since that is tagged in your question.  But you must then be mindful about validating input, lest someone supply an invalid and malicious parameter.

For example, you could use the following code in `call_forward.php` (note `.php`, not `.xml`):

```
<?php
$number = @$_GET['PhoneNumber'];
if (!preg_match('|\+?[0-9- ]+|', $number))
    die('Invalid PhoneNumber');
header('Content-type: text/xml');
?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial><?php echo $number; ?></Dial>
    <Say>Hello, Have a good day!</Say>
</Response>
```